# Backbone.js: Best way to save a changed model id to the server

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I want to allow the user to change the `id` of a model in a collection.

Then I have the problem that when I call `model.save()` the model is saved to the wrong location. It is `put` to the url of the new id instead to the url of the old id

```
var model = collection.get('oldid');
model.set({id: 'newId'}); // set by the user through the ui
model.save();
```

This will save to `collectionUrl/ + 'newId'` instead of `collectionUrl/ + 'oldId'`

I want to save (put) {id: 'newId'} to the old url.

What is the most consistent way of doing this?

Comment: Any idea why the client would want to change the id? I'd think there's something funny going on there.

Comment: Do you mean the client side code or the user by `client`?

Comment: I general the id should represent a key (usually a primary key) associated with the row/document in a table/collection on the server side. The id should be generated on the server side when you save a backbone model on the client side and attached to the model on server response. Users should not be able to change the id otherwise you will run into the problems you described above.

Comment: the user should have an option to change the `id` (should be able to change the primary key) to another unique id

Comment: @innotune: I can't think of a reason why user should be able to change the id. If it is enough to just change the id then destroy the old record and create a new one. Could it be actually that you want to show some kind of human readable name in the url? In that case you should match `/collection/:name` in the controller and search for the matching name from the collection. Let id/cid thing work as it does.

Comment: i see no reason why a id needs to be immutable. example: the collection is a translation of a directory structure, the id is the filename. renaming a file should be a logical operation and adding a pseudo id would add unnecessary overhead and (possible) bugs (a filename needs to be unique, so i have check agains id and against name)

Comment: @innotune: id is not a filename. It is generally assumed to be nonchanging thing for the lifetime of the record.

Comment: i think that the only requirement for a primary key is that it should be unique. you're right that in general it is assumed that the primary key is immutable (especially when dealing with orm this is mandatory), but this also depends on the use case. if i model something that acts like a filesystem it makes sense to use the filename as the primary key (there is no contradiction in doing this), it makes assertions easier than using an artificial immutable key. but this is way too off topic. i am looking for a clean and logical solution to change the id in backbone

Comment: In my opinion you should never change the ID of a model.  If the id changes it's a new object.

Comment: I am using backbone to manage file system events. It seems appropriate to use the file-path as the id. Ofcourse, the file-path can change.. which leads to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is so edge case that there's no best practices for it.

I would try overwriting [Backbone.sync](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1032) and/or [Backbone.Model save](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L294) to make backbone behave that way. I did a similar thing when using backbone in Air app when saving straight to local database.

--edit

Or maybe [Backbone.Model url](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L326).

Comment: you're right, in the end I had to modify the `save`, `url` and `set` method. If anybody is interested in the source, you can find it here https://gist.github.com/fe25760ca44414ab2707 If this would be modified in backbone.js it would just add 1 line to each function

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved by setting the wait option to true on the save method of the model. 
This prevents the model's url from changing until after the server returns an updated representation with a new id. I've tried it out and it seems to work great!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any framework, server side or client side would support that out of the box. Best way would be to do your own AJAX request to your own endpoint on the server. I would question why you need to do that though, I can't think of any reason that would be a good idea.

Comment: the standard restful approach would be to send a PUT /oldid with {id: 'newId'} to the server. I don't think you need a custom ajax request for that.

Comment: @innotune: Have you considered the case when two clients update the same record? The second client would still have reference to the old id when trying to update the record whose id has just changed because of the first client's update.

Comment: you're right this is an issue, but when one user deletes a record this would happen nonetheless. In the app I develop each user has only access to his private records. thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit roundabout, but you could create a separate unique id (specified using the model's idAttribute), then 'id' is just another property.

Most (all...?) frameworks assume that an id is unique and unchanging.

Just know that changing the id has so many implications. Any references other objects have to that id will now be broken, urls referencing the previous id will be broken, etc...